# What does "while :;" mean?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I know what a `while` loop is. However, I've only seen it work with:

```
while [condition]
while ![condition]
while TRUE (infinite loop)
```

Where the statement after `while` has to be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

There is a shell builtin command named `:`. It is described as a dummy command doing nothing, but I do not know if it is the same here, even if can it be `TRUE` or `FALSE`.  Maybe it is something different, but what?

Comment: The command `:` does nothing but always exits with return code 0.  So, it is the same was `while true` (assuming your system has a `true` executable).

Comment: @John1024 It returns zero unless the evaluation of its arguments causes an error by, for example, assigning a value to a readonly variable.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, if the `:` command is never executed, it won't return 0. That's overly pedantic in my opinion though.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
while
  first list of commands
do
  second list of commands
done
```

which runs the second list of commands in a loop as long as the first list of commands (so the last run in that list) is successful.

In that *first list of commands*, you can use the `[` command to do various kinds of tests, or you can use the `:` null command that does nothing and returns success, or any other command.

```
while :; do cmd; done
```

Runs `cmd` over and over forever as `:` always returns success. That's the *forever* loop. You could use the `true` command instead to make it more legible:

```
while true; do cmd; done
```

People used to prefer `:` as `:` was always builtin while `true` was not (a long time ago; most shells have `true` builtin nowadays)¹.

Other variants you might see:

```
while [ 1 ];  do cmd; done
```

Above, we're calling the `[` command to test whether the "1" string is non-empty (so always true as well)

```
while ((1)); do cmd; done
```

Using the Korn/bash/zsh `((...))` syntax to mimic the `while(1) { ...; }` of C.

Or more convoluted ones like `until false; do cmd; done`, `until ! true`...

Those are sometimes aliased like:

```
alias forever='while :; do'
```

So you can do something like:

```
forever cmd; done
```

Few people realise that the condition is a *list* of commands. For instance, you see people writing:

```
while :; do
  cmd1
  cmd2 || break
  cmd3
done
```

When they could have written:

```
while
  cmd1
  cmd2
do
  cmd3
done
```

It does make sense for it to be a *list* as you often want to do things like `while cmd1 && cmd2; do...; done` which are command lists as well.

In any case, note that `[` is a command like any other (though it's built-in in modern Bourne-like shells), it doesn't have to be used solely in the `if`/`while`/`until` condition lists, and those condition lists don't have to use that command more than any other command.

---

¹ `:` is also shorter and accepts arguments (which it ignores). While the behaviour of `true` or `false` is unspecified if you pass it any argument. So one may do for instance:

```
while : you wait; do
  something
done
```

But, the behaviour of:

```
until false is true; do
  something
done
```

is unspecified (though it would work in most shell/`false` implementations).

Answer (score 12):

`while :` is an infinite loop. `:` just does nothing (successfully).

So if you want your shell to hang forever doing nothing, you can write it as

```
while :
do
    :
done
```

Or in a single line with `;` instead of newlines: `while :; do :; done`

`while :` is usually used if you want to do something repeatedly without a special condition attached. You might use `continue`, `break` statements within the loop to control it or to move the condition to the end of the loop like a `do ... while` construct.

Answer (score 12):

> howsoever, the statement after while has to be either TRUE or FALSE.

No, the command in the condition part can be any command<sup>(*)</sup> . *All* shell commands have some return value, and the `while` loop (as well as the `if` conditional) take return values of zero as "true", and all others as "false". <sub>(* or a list of several commands, the last one counts)</sub>

As for `:`, [Bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins) tells clearly what the return status of that is:

> `: [arguments]`
>    Do nothing beyond expanding arguments and performing redirections.
>     The return status is zero.

The `help` builtin is even more clear:

```
 $ help :
 [...]
 No effect; the command does nothing
 Exit Status:
 Always succeeds.
```

Comment: `s/any command/any sequence of commands/`, as 
Stéphane makes clear.